# Linux command for finding users who logged in on a particular date

Tags: linux, command

I am trying to find a way to list all users who logged on Feb 17, 2020
Is there a simple way to do it? I found some really complex way on some websites 
by piping the output of one command into the output of other.

Comment: Connecting output to input with pipes is one of the most powerful, and at the same time elegant and intuitive  features of UNIX. If you want to work with UNIX-like systems, I strongly suggest you take advantage of every opportunity to practice pipes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `last` command with `--time-format` option to change the time format, then filtering the results through `grep`:

```
 last --time-format=iso |grep '2020-02-17'
```

More better:

```
last --time-format=iso -s 2020-02-17 -t 2020-02-18
```